# os.environ.get returning None while the terminal returns correct environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables

I've set the environment variable in the shell like this

```
export DEPLOY=development
```

and running this returns "development"

```
echo $DEPLOY
```

However... this returns none in python.

```
import os
os.environ.get("DEPLOY")
```

and this raises a key error

```
os.environ["DEPLOY"]
```

I've deleted the .pyc files and restarted my IDE...

Any ideas?

Comment: If Python is not a child of the process where you ran the `export`, of course it can't inherit the variable from that.

Comment: So define the variable in the working directly of the python code?

Comment: If you mean "working directory" then no, that's not at all what "parent process" means. If you run Python from the shell prompt where you previously executed the `export`, that Python instance does get a copy of the variable (regardless of which directory you are running it in) as long as you didn't `exit` that shell in the meantime. (This is all assuming you are not on Windows, where the mechanics are more twisty and perverse.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export DEPLOY=development` only changes the environment *for your shell, and programs that shell starts*.

Because you're starting Python *from your IDE*, not from the shell, the Python interpreter is not a child (or grandchild) process of that shell, and so does not inherit the shell's environment variables.

Comment: Thanks understand this completly now, but still may help someone else in the future. Cheers for the answer.