# Why doesn't os.environ.get() return a variable created by sourcing a .env file, but echo can find it?

Tags: python

Here's one of those rare questions that gets asked a lot on SO, but there's no answer.  I'll ask it again a little differently.

I'm trying to set an environment variable using a file and then read the variable in python.  That should be pretty basic.

However, check this out:

```
$ cat .env.test
NAME=Bob
$ cat x.py
import os
print(os.environ.get("NAME"))
$ (source .env.test;  echo $NAME) 
Bob
$ (source .env.test;  python3 x.py)
None
```

Isn't that strange?  Why doesn't it work?

Is it because I didn't write `export` in the .env file?  **If I add `export`, it does work.** But why?  Isn't this what `source` is supposed to do?

```
$ cat .env.test
export NAME=Bob
$ cat x.py
import os
print(os.environ.get("NAME"))
$ (source .env.test;  echo $NAME) 
Bob
$ (source .env.test;  python3 x.py)
Bob
```

I think the community could use an explanation about how sub-shells work, how `source` works and where python is looking for the environment variables, to answer this once and for all.  Can you do that?

**Related Questions**

- [os.environ.get returning None while the terminal returns correct environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858766/os-environ-get-returning-none-while-the-terminal-returns-correct-environment-var)
- [In flask, os.environ.get() return None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991850/in-flask-os-environ-get-return-none)
- [Python os.environ.get not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489567/python-os-environ-get-not-returning-value)

Comment: `export` is what adds the variable to the environment. In your first example, you only have a shell variable.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Python, but with understanding how your particular dshell works.

Comment: you don't define a env var, just a var.

Comment: _reviews the related questions to see if they're really based on the same misapprehension_

Comment: ...so, the claimed preexisting question *os.environ.get not returning value* is ambiguous -- we don't have enough details to reproduce the problem, so we can't tell if it's the same shell-vs-env dichotomy; so it's not in any way clear that it's really a duplicate at all.

Comment: The flask one, by contrast, has `sudo` in the way. That completely changes things, because sudo is often configured to discard environment variables. And in fact, the OP acknowledges in the comments on the question that that's their problem -- so it's completely distinct from this one.

Comment: And the first one you listed doesn't make it clear that the OP there understands that they need to start Python _from the same shell_ where they ran the `export`.

Comment: ...in fact, the OP there is clear that they're starting Python _from their IDE_, not from the shell; so that too is distinct.

Comment: ...I've added community-wiki answers to the two of those questions that have enough information to be answerable, and added an appropriate close vote to the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var=value` does not define an environment variable unless the option `set -a` is defined. *By default, it only defines a shell variable.*

Non-exported shell variables do not survive an `exec()` boundary -- that is to say, when you start a new executable, only environment variables survive.

---

To export all variables sourced in from a file, enable the `set -a` shell option before sourcing it, as described in [How to set environment variables from .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267413/shell-how-to-set-environment-variables-from-env-file):

```
$ (set -a; source .env.test; exec python3 x.py)
```

In the above case we don't need to turn off `set -a` because it's scoped to a subshell that exits when the `)` is hit -- or even before, because we can use `exec` to tell the subshell to replace itself with Python without forking again.

For a more general case, when this is used inside a script that's going to continue to run for a while, it would instead look like:

```
set -a            # enable auto-export
source .env.test  # source file content
set +a            # disable auto-export
```

Comment: Ah, shell variables vs environment-variable.  Got it.  Follow-up question: In this SO question, I'm trying to accomplish this with a file, can `source` be used in some way to implicitly create `export`'d environment variables?

Comment: `(export $(cat .env.test | xargs);  python3 x.py)` seems to do it

Comment: That's buggy -- I don't recommend it. Better to use `set -a; source .env.test; set +a; python3 x.py`.

Comment: @101010, ...to go beyond a bare assertion re: "that's buggy", try `var='value with=multiple words=contained'` -- with the `export $(cat | xargs)` approach you'll see `var`, `with`, and `words` as three separate environment variables.

Comment: @101010, ...for an even more, err, _interesting_ case, try `var=$'value\nwith=newlines\nbetween=words'` -- that'll break a lot of other xargs-based approaches (when run in bash, that command results in a variable with newlines in it, not backslashes or `n` characters between the words). Also test with regular single quotes and literal newlines instead of `\n` sequences, when you're trying to find a suitably robust approach.

Comment: The one-liner is a great solution to this SO article.  Thank you for the follow-up explanation.  I added the one-liner to your answer.

Comment: @101010, note that in the subshell case some additional optimizations are possible. You don't need `set +a` if the subshell is about to be destroyed, and you can use `exec` to tell the shell to just replace the subshell process with Python instead of forking off Python as a child -- which means you end up not paying any extra cost for the subshell at all, because the fork that starts the subshell is paid off by avoiding the fork that would otherwise be used to create a process in which to start Python.